# Symfony CMF StaticContent show all child blocks in PHPCTRee?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-cmf

Does anybody know how I can make all child blocks show up on the CMF Tree in the `Sonata Admin` for the `StaticContent` class?

The way our system uses the `Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\ContentBundle\Doctrine\Phpcr\StaticContent` class is to just use it as a content document that we can attach other blocks to.  I thought that was the purpose of the `ContentBundle`.  Instead only blocks inside of this additionalInfoBlock container block appear in the tree. Unless I am doing something wrong. I have looked at

`Symfony/Cmf/Bundle/ContentBundle/Resources/config/doctrine-model/StaticContent.phpcr.xml`:

```
<child name="additionalInfoBlock">
   <cascade><cascade-persist /></cascade>
</child>
```

There has to be way to get all the child blocks show. I just dont want to start hacking the `PHPCRTree` class to do this. Do I extend `StaticContent` and hopefully it will show all children? How do I go about this if that is the answer.  Or is there another setting.

See this image below of what I can see in `jackrabbitexplorer` vs what is in the CMF Tree in the `Sonata admi`n

![Sonata Admin and jackrabbitexplorer representation of StaticContent class children]http://i43.tinypic.com/160whlt.png