# StaticContent show all child blocks in PHPCTRee?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-cmf

Does anybody know how I can make all child blocks show up on the CMF Tree in the Sonata Admin for the `StaticContent` class? The way our system uses the `Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\ContentBundle\Doctrine\Phpcr\StaticContent` class is to just use it as a content document that we can attach other blocks to.  I thought that was the purpose of the `ContentBundle`.  Instead only blocks inside of this `additionalInfoBlock` container block appear in the tree. Unless I am doing something wrong. I have looked at

**`Symfony/Cmf/Bundle/ContentBundle/Resources/config/doctrine-model/StaticContent.phpcr.xml`:**

```
<child name="additionalInfoBlock">
<cascade><cascade-persist /></cascade>
</child>
```

There has to be way to get all the child blocks show. I just dont want to start hacking the `PHPCRTree` class to do this. Do I extend `StaticContent` and hopefully it will show all children? How do I go about this if that is the answer.  Or is there another setting.

See this image below of what I can see in jackrabbitexplorer vs what is in the CMF Tree in the Sonata admin:

[image]

Comment: this is the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21146260/symfony-cmf-staticcontent-show-all-child-blocks-in-phpctree

Answer (score 1):

You opened an issue on the github project. That is the best way to get help for the cmf. https://github.com/symfony-cmf/TreeBrowserBundle/issues/57